# Adaptive card in MS Teams doesn't return input field data using Action.Execute

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to create a bot in Microsoft Teams. I'm trying to get some user input, but I can't get the data that is entered in the Adaptive Card to be returned.

I've tried the following template for the card that I send as activity:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.5",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "medium",
            "weight": "bolder",
            "text": "${Title}",
            "horizontalAlignment": "center",
            "wrap": true,
            "style": "heading"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "user",
            "label": "Username",
            "isRequired": true,
            "errorMessage": "Username is required"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Execute",
            "title": "Send",
            "verb": "test",
            "data": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

That seems to work fine and yields the following card in Teams:
[image: Adaptive Cards in MS Teams]

After entering some data in the input field and using the send button the endpoint receives the message back containing the following body:

```json
{
    "name": "adaptiveCard/action",
    "type": "invoke",
    "timestamp": "2023-06-02T09:59:04.892Z",
    //other data that's not relevant
    "value": {
        "action": {
            "type": "Action.Execute",
            "title": "Send",
            "data": {},
            "verb": "test"
        },
        "trigger": "manual"
    },
}
```

The [Action.Execute](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Execute.html) documentation states that:

> Gathers input fields, merges with optional data field, and sends an event to the client. Clients process the event by sending an Invoke activity of type adaptiveCard/action to the target Bot.

I expect the data from the input field to be returned, but it's missing from the response. Even when inspecting the request send from a browser running Teams I can't see the input data being send to the server. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We have the exact same problem with our app ATM. It's been working great for a year - then all of the sudden yesterday the input fields stopped working. 
They work if I use the app via Teams running in Google Chrome. But it doesn't work if use Firefox, Edge or the desktop app. 

What happens if you run the app via Teams in Chrome? Could be interesting to know if this is caused by some changes in Teams or the browsers maybe.

Comment: @InversionDK I had already tried the 'old' app and Firefox before and neither worked. I've tried Chrome and it also doesn't work.

Comment: We are able to repro this issue. We have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: I was actually also able to get it in a non-working state through Chrome on another computer. It seemed to be related to the browser, but apparently not :/
@Prasad-MSFT any update on this will be greatly appreciated - thanks a lot.

Comment: @InversionDK- Currently there is no update from engineering team side regarding this. We will inform in this thread once we hear anything. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Do you have an update on this bug? It's quite a serious one - our Teams app is essentially broken until this is resolved. Is there an ETA for when it will be fixed? Thanks

Comment: Apologies. Currently there is no ETA to share. We have updated engineering team about the severity of this issue. We will inform in this thread once we hear any update from them. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I thought I was going crazy until I found this thread! I just started developing a new MSTeams bot yesterday and could not get Action.Execute to send Input data. Is there still no response from MSFT on this @Prasad-MSFT?

Comment: This issue is fixed now. Adaptive card in Ms Teams now returns input field data using Action.Execute Tested in MS Teams desktop (Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.20958) and web client. `"value": {
        "action": {
            "type": "Action.Execute",
            "id": "execute",
            "title": "Execute",
            "data": {
                "action": "execute",
                "someText": "qwerty"
            },
            "verb": "execute"
        },
        "trigger": "manual"
    },`