# NodeJS botbuilder Adaptive Card User Input Not Included in `onAdaptiveCardInvoke` Event when Sent to a Channel in MS Teams

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm using Node.js with Typescript and the `"botbuilder": "^4.20.0"` package to create a MS Teams bot that sends interactive Adaptive Cards to users or a channel, and collect some input. My problem is that when the Adaptive Card is sent to a channel, the user input is not being returned in the `onAdaptiveCardInvoke` event.

Below is my relevant code:

Generate the Activity

```js
public generate(): Promise<Partial<Activity>> {
    const card = {
      type: "AdaptiveCard",
      $schema: "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      version: "1.4",
      body: [
        {
          type: "Input.Text",
          placeholder: "John",
          label: "First Name",
          id: "firstName",
        },
        {
          type: "ActionSet",
          actions: [
            {
              type: "Action.Execute",
              title: "Execute"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    return Promise.resolve({
      attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)],
      summary: "Test",
      type: ActivityTypes.Message
    });
  }
```

Send the Notification

```js
  public async notify(contact: MsTeamsContactInfo): Promise<void> {
    await this.adapter.continueConversationAsync(this.teamsBotId, contact.commObject, async (turn) => {
      const activity = (await this.testCard.generate());
      if (contact.kind !== "user") {
        await TeamsInfo.sendMessageToTeamsChannel(turn, activity, contact.channel.id, this.teamsBotId);
      } else {
        await turn.sendActivity(activity);
      }
    });
  }
```

Catch the `execute` event

```js
public override async onAdaptiveCardInvoke(context: TurnContext, invokeValue: AdaptiveCardInvokeValue): Promise<AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse> {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(invokeValue));
  }
```

The expected behavior is that `invokeValue.action.data.firstName` will contain the user's input from the Adaptive Card regardless of whether the card is sent to an individual or a channel. However, when sent to a channel, `invokeValue.action.data` is `undefined`.

So far, I've tried adding `inlineAction` to the buttons, set `associatedInputs: "auto"`, changed the action to `Action.Submit`, and tried sending the message in a few different ways (`sendActivity`, `createConversationAsync`, `sendMessageToTeamsChannel`). All of my tries didn't work

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We have raised bug for similar issue where [Adaptive card in MS Teams doesn't return input field data using Action.Execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76389213/adaptive-card-in-ms-teams-doesnt-return-input-field-data-using-action-execute). Could you please confirm if your issue is in similar line?

Comment: I appreciate your input. Certainly, there are similarities between the issues, and they may indeed be related. However, the problems I'm facing are not exactly the same. I am consistently receiving the input when it's from a direct, one-on-one chat, but it becomes problematic when it's sent through a channel.
If I understand correctly, in your situation, you're not receiving any input irrespective of the type of contact.

Comment: It is happening in channel scope as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1295145/why-isnt-action-execute-including-input-values-whe). We will inform engineering team about this issue and update this thread once we hear from them. Thanks!

Comment: This issue is fixed now. Adaptive card in Ms Teams now returns input field data using Action.Execute Tested in MS Teams desktop (Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.20958) and web client. `"value": { "action": { "type": "Action.Execute", "id": "execute", "title": "Execute",  "data": { "action": "execute", "someText": "qwerty" }, "verb": "execute" },         "trigger": "manual" }`